# from java applet value to MVC .net or from java applet value to MVC .net with javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, applet

I'm trying string json from applet to ASP.NET MVC

```
map = new LinkedHashMap();
map.put("xxx",xxx);
string json= myfunction(map);
```

I want to take string json or any string  from applet to ASP.NET MVC or javascript

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Edit your code inside a code block (indent everything on a new line with 4 or more spaces or select the code and press the button that looks like this: `{}`). It'll make it easier to read the code.

Comment: You should add some more details about what you are doing and especially about what you have already tried. Please add some more of your code to your Question.

Comment: i have sent to java applet with <param name="name" value="@viewBag.name"/> and  i want to return value from applet to MVC.net insert to database with applet and get a id from database return to display html or MVC .net

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).